# Values inserted to bigint column comes out as date

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this;

```
CREATE TABLE `runlog` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contentid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `contentType` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `overlay` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `option` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `trt` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `contentaltid` int DEFAULT '0',
  `channelName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` bigint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=225129 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In the datetime column the intent is to store a unix timestamp. I previously had a colum that kept a "timestamp" datatype. I ran `update runlog set 'datetime' unix_timestamp(timestamp) * 1000` when I made the change and the previously created records are correct. But from this point on, if I do

`insert into runlog  (contentid, contenttype, overlay, datetime, trt) values (3107, 0, 'None', 1639161815692, 185.75 )`

in the table, the record inserted says;

```
'225126', '3107', '0', 'LATE', NULL, NULL, '0', 'East', '20211209230329'
```

Why would it take 1639161815692 and return 20211209230329?

Comment: I find more mysterious the fact that `'None'` gets converted to `'LATE'`. My guess is that you're querying a different row. (BTW, I [cannot reproduce it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2d009505a6d4c79dde217445fba34639)).

Comment: Do you have any triggers on this table that are changing the values before insert?

Comment: You're either looking at the wrong records (maybe some rows that were inserted in earlier tests were you didn't invoke `unix_timestamp()` yet) or there's a BEFORE INSERT trigger. Let us know if you gather more information.